# How can I use Firefox with Ubuntu firewall (gufw)?

Tags: gufw

I don't know how can I allow the permission for Firefox in the gufw firewall.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Unless you restrict outgoing traffic with gufw, Firefox shouldn't be affected by the firewall.

Answer (score 3):

The most secure way to set your firewall UFW is probably to:

- deny any entry
- deny any exit

and then configure every rules to allow exactly only what you want.

---

So if you only what to allow Firefox (or any other web application) to use HTTP and HTTPS protocols, then add this rule in GUFW and reboot.

With:

- port 80 for HTTP protocol
- port 443 for HTTPS protocol

[image]

---

With such settings, you will have to add a rule for every needs, examples:

- to allow Thunderbird to use your email account, add a new rule
- to allow Skipe, add a new rule
- ....

Answer (score 2):

Unless you specifically restrict outgoing traffic with `gufw` rules, Firefox shouldn't be affected by the firewall.

As I understand it, by default, gufw won't be restricting any outbound and related traffic.  If, for example, I send Firefox to https://askubuntu.com/ and I have a generally restrictive inbound rules set, gufw will still allow Firefox to go outbound to askubuntu.com and get related information from that connection, such as actual site content, and allow that through.

Comment: But suppose you want to Deny ALL outgoing and incoming traffic.  However, you want to apply a several rules to allow Firefox, and only Firefox, incoming and outgoing traffic capability?

Answer (score 1):

Open GUFW and click on the plus sign. In the first tab select the following and hit the add button for each one of them.

`Allow` `In` `Service` `HTTP`

`Allow` `Out` `Service` `HTTP`

`Allow` `In` `Service` `HTTPS`

`Allow` `Out` `Service` `HTTPS`

And you're done.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo default deny incoming  
sudo default deny outgoing
```

internet

```
sudo ufw allow out 53  
sudo ufw allow out http  
sudo ufw allow out https  
sudo ufw allow out 8080
```

gmail-thunderbird

```
sudo ufw allow proto tcp from 173.194.0.0/16   
sudo ufw allow out to 173.194.0.0/16 
sudo ufw allow out to 74.125.0.0/16 port 465 proto tcp
```

hotmail-thunderbird

```
sudo ufw allow proto tcp from 207.46.0.0/16   
sudo ufw allow out to 207.46.0.0/16 port    
sudo ufw allow out to 65.52.0.0/14 port 587 proto tcp
```